# Caliburn Micro keyboard shortcuts not working

Tags: wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, caliburn.micro

Given following XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Solution.Views.SomeView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    xmlns:cm="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
    cm:Message.Attach="[Key F11] = [ToggleFullScreen]">
    <Grid>
        <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0">
            <xctk:IconButton Style="{StaticResource ToolBarButton}" ToolTip="Full Screen (F11)"
                cm:Message.Attach="ToggleFullScreen">
                <Image Style="{StaticResource ToolBarButtonImage}" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Img/Full_Screen32.png"/>
            </xctk:IconButton>
        </ToolBar>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

F11 will not trigger `ToggleFullScreen` method but button click will. Changing [Key F11] to [Gesture Alt+F] or [Gesture F11] does not work either...

Why is this and how do you get keyboard shortcuts to work with Caliburn Micro 3.2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the official [Scenario.KeyBinding](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/tree/master/samples/scenarios/Scenario.KeyBinding) example on GitHub. Pay special attention to the `Configure()` method in the `Bootstrapper` class. It's the code in there that enables the key bindings. If you add a `ToggleFullScreen()` method to the `ShellViewModel` class in the sample project and set the `cal:Message.Attach` attached property of the `ShellView` to `[Key F11] = [ToggleFullScreen]` just like you have done in your example, it should work.

So you need to copy the code from the `Configure()` method into your bootstrapper and also bring in the classes under the `Input` folder of the sample project into your project.

Comment: This works but only if 'cal:Message.Attach' is in the `ShellView` and method in `ShellViewModel`. If I try to use `cal:Message.Attach` in some other View and the method is in that Views VM it doesn't work... Any idea how to get it to work  solution wide?

Comment: Where is this "some other view" and how do you instantiate it?

Comment: It's in the ViewModels folder together with the `ShellViewModel` and it is instantiated in the `ShellViewModel` like this: `SomeProperty = new SomeViewModel();` `Activate(SomeProperty);` 
That feels wrong but I just stared with CM and could not find an example how additional VMs should be instantiated with `SimpleContainer`...